# Getting vector feature information (distance and extent ) on OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, vector, distance

I have basic WMS layer and vector layer in OpenLayers. Using EditingToolbar I can draw some  features as shown below

[image]

Then I want to get some information (like distance and extent) of drawn features in any format. At the movement I stuck on above point. 
Can you give me some tips or sample code or some links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get vector layer extent:

```
vector.getDataExtent();
```

for getting features:

```
vector.features;
```

for getting first feature geometry:

```
vector.features[0].geometry.x
vector.features[0].geometry.y
```

for getting centroid of your first feature:

```
vector.features[0].geometry.getCentroid();
```

for getting first feature coordinate as string:

```
vector.features[0].geometry.toString();
```

for getting distance one point to another (it cant give geodetic result):

```
var p1 =   new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(10,20);
var p2 =   new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(30,40);

var distance = p1.distanceTo(p2)
```

Comment: What's the equivalent of vector.features[0].geometry.x in OpenLayers 3?

Answer (score 2):

Use a SelectFeature control, and listen to `featureselected` events on the layer. The listener can use `event.feature.geometry.getArea()` to get the selected polygon's area, for example.

Comment: Yes ,Thanks for answer,can u give some sample codes or some links